# How to run a 30 minute API call in django

Tags: python, django, sockets, python-requests

In my django app, I have a function that is triggered by an action (a republishing action) where after the republish endpoint is hit, that function is triggered to check its status for 30 minutes via another API call. That function is:

```
timeout = time.time() + 60 * 30
        published_flag = False
    while time.time() < timeout:
                data = requests.get(apiUrl + dist_id).json()
                try:
                    published_flag = data['flags']
                    if published_flag:
                        break
                    else:
                        time.sleep(5)
                        continue
                except KeyError:
                    break
```

This timeout is 30 minutes and is very long. But 30 minutes is the worst case scenario when the flag status would change. This action can be triggered multiple times (multiple republish buttons can be pressed). The endpoint essentially times out as 30 minutes is too long for an endpoint to work. So I push the data via web sockets to the frontend.

Is there a smarter way to do this?

Comment: I think you can make use of `celery` http://www.celeryproject.org to move your slow task run in background. and maintain a web socket connection to notify your client when task is done.

Comment: But there could be 6-7 republish actions at one time. So for each of those, do i scale the number of workers?

Comment: yes, you of cause. you can take a look of the `celery` tutorial   http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#starting-the-worker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Enix wrote you should use Celery. But you don't need a lot of workers. Actually never call `sleep` inside celery tasks. You can just retry it later. So every task will be really short and you need just 1-2 workers.

```
@app.task(bind=True, max_retries=60*30/5)
def do_whatever(self, dist_id):
    data = requests.get(apiUrl + dist_id).json()
    if 'flags' not in data:
        self.retry(countdown=5)
```